# Google Mobile Friendly Test doesn't download css/js/images reliably (cloudfront + ALB)

Tags: google, amazon-cloudfront

I use CloudFront and ALB with AWS and my site always looks good from mobile, desktop and tablet browsers.

But in the Google mobile-friendly tool, it often doesn't have random images, css, and javascript

TEST URL: (ALB + cloudfront) (Errors on js/images/css randomly)

https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?url=https%3A%2F%2Fphppointofsale.com%2F

EC2: (Never errors on my css/js, images)

https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.blastohosting.com%2F

What could be the cause of this? I have looked and cloudfront logs and they are all 200 status and appears the requests never make it to cloudfront. My site works fine besides this test

Comment: Try to fetch and render in Google Search Console, See what's issue is shown there.

Comment: looks fine and no missing resources

Comment: Do you happen to use javascript/ajax to load the images when some condition is met?

Comment: No I do not use js to load images

Comment: Hey, how did you fix your issue? I have the same problem. It seems google sometimes doesn't even try to load the main css file.

Comment: I never did fix it. Google groups said this is known behavior. I find it crazy